# Extends a TabHost in to linearLayout

Tags: android

I tried to imlement a tab to add for a linearLayout. This is the code which I wrote.

```
package android.warna;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class XmlTabView extends LinearLayout{

    View view;

    public XmlTabView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        view = new View(context);
         view = createTab(context);
         this.addView(view);

    }

    private android.view.ViewGroup createTab(final Context context) {
        TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(context);
        tabHost.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(context);
        tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        tabHost.addView(tabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 65, 0, 0);
        tabHost.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabChild1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Child_1");
        tabChild1.setIndicator("Child 1");

         tabChild1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                TextView txt = new TextView(context);
                txt.setText("Test Child 1");
                txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12f);
                txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                return txt;
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(tabChild1);

        **Resources res = getResources();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(context,LinearLayOut.class);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("country").setIndicator("country",
                 res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                    .setContent(intent);**


        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        TabHost.TabSpec tabChild3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Child_3");
        tabChild3.setIndicator("Child 3");
        tabChild3.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                TextView txt = new TextView(context);
                txt.setText("Test Child 3");
                txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12f);
                txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                return txt;
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(tabChild3);

        return tabHost;
    }
}
```

It's working. But the problem is I can't call a activity like following.

```
    **Resources res = getResources();
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(context,LinearLayOut.class);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("country").setIndicator("country",
             res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                .setContent(intent);**
```

If I call a activity for that tab, it's not working.
Please can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

`TabSpec.setContent()` takes a `View`, since you're using a `Layout`, I believe you want `TabSpec.setContentView()` (which takes a layout as the content).

Comment: Also, you don't need the `Intent`, you can create the `LinearLayout` directly, call `TabSpec.setContentView()`, and start adding to it.

Comment: But I want to set the view of a already created activity for that tab.

Comment: Just curious, why are you creating the Activity ahead of time, instead of simply creating an `Intent` for that activity, and adding that to the tab?